# Mouse Over in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, onmouseover

I have a `CSS element` thats been declared something like :

```
span.green_box {width:5px, height:7px ....and other specifications.}
```

I really dont know any CSS and its not my code. However I do understand that what it does is that it is creating a green coloured box of the given dimensions.

Now in my Django-template I want to display a text on mouseover on this `green_box`. Just displaying a text would not have been a problem because its done something like this in my django template :

```
<span class="green_box" title="I am green."></span>
```

And this works. But I have to refactor it to display something like `I am Green and today is 28-6-2013`

So for this I have a custom tag, `get_todays_date` that returns the current date as a string.

And I want to do something like,

```
<span class="green_box" onmouseover="I am Green and today is %s" % {{get_todays_date}}></span>
```

My intention is to reproduce the value returned by `get_todays_date` into `%s`. I wrote it to describe the structure. This obviously doesn't work. I've looked over on other similar questions but their solution don't work. Most are for mouse over on an image, and a predefined text. So how can I display the text including the value returned by `get_todays_date` on `mouseover` on the `green_box`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no string formatting in django templates as there is in python. There is also a template tag which is able to retrieve todays date (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now). Hope this leads into the right direction.

You could try something like this:

```
<span class="green_box" onmouseover="I am Green and today is {% now "d-n-Y" %}">
```